# How to catch POST requested data submitted to a javascript page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js

The request is sent from: 
(This is remote unknown source & not in my control)

> **xyz.php**
>
> ```
> <form action='https_:_//xyz.com/javascriptFile' method='POST'>
>     <input type='text' name='data' />
> </form>
> ```

to:
(My front-end js file)

> **javascriptFile.js**
>
> `Need to catch the php POST request **data** here`

Answer (score 0):

Simple form exmaple

```
<form id="input_form" name"input_form" method="POST" onsubmit="return send();">
    <input type='text' name="first_name" value="John"/>
</form>
```

JS code:

```
<script>
function send() {

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './path/your_php_file.php',
        data:$('#input_form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
           //on succeess
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            // for error handling
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</<script>
```

If you want to get access form data:

```
<script>
     let get_first_name='<?php echo $_GET['url_param_name'];?>';
</script>
```

Comment: No, I can't post the request to php file. the request will come from remote php file and i need to catch it in my local js file. remote php will send the request to my js file, but cqam't catch it

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you want to fire off a request from a php file, and you want that to be caught on a JS file?

What you are referring here is, you need a server side JS file that is built to handle POST requests. You need a web framework like `http` or `express`, something like that which will run on a Node.JS Server and will handle a POST request directed to any specific route.

For example, if you are using express to create a POST route:

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
 
app.post('/javascriptFile', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})
 
app.listen(3000)
```

This will catch all the POST requests coming to `localhost:3000/javascriptFile`, and if you deploy this server on `www.xyz.com`, then you can very well send POST requests to `xyz.com/javascriptFile`

Comment: Is it possible to catch from front-end ?

Comment: Nope it isn't, front-end was never created to perform this operation! These HTTP routes are supposed to be hidden away in the server (back-end) which will handle the requests accordingly. 

In your case you have a `xyz.php` file which I assume is the code that will run on the client-side. This form will be loaded whenever a user visits your php file, and the client side logic must be sending off these form details to a server. That's the only job of your front-end.

Your back-end will now receive these details and do whatever you want to do, like storing in a database or something similar.

Comment: xyz.php is not in my hand. A remote source (unknown php site) submit a form to my url (indicate my front-end javascript file), I need to get all the form data that source submitting me.

Comment: In your scenario, the data flow should look something like this:

PHP submits data to a server via `POST` request -> Your Server has a `POST` route that will store data for all the form submissions -> Your front-end JS file should retrieve back the specific data from server via a `GET` request. I fear you cannot skip the intermediate step

Comment: yes, exacly... How can it be possible now ?